# How to set min and max selecting days in MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker

I am using Material DatePicker for selecting range. I want to have the ability to select only future dates.
I am trying to setCalendarConstraints, but it works only for a month.
Is there any way to set min and max selecting dates?

```
val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
builder.setCalendarConstraints(
        CalendarConstraints.Builder().setStart(System.currentTimeMillis()).build()
)
val dialog = builder.build()
```

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: I am using com.google.android.material.datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using System.currentTimeMillis(), try using calendar as specified in the android [doc](http://onsole.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/vtny-bf595/database/vtny-bf595/data).

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// c.set(year, month, 1);
// c.getTimeInMillis();

val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
builder.setCalendarConstraints(
        CalendarConstraints.Builder().setStart(c.getTimeInMillis()).build()
)
val dialog = builder.build()
```

Comment: I've tried this approach. I can't select a date from the previous month but can select the previous date for the current month